# WCF Service not showing my functions

Tags: wcf, web-services, asp.net-4.0

I have written following code, but only first method in service shows up in client side but rest of two doesn't :(

any one guide me what could be the issue?

**ServiceInterface:**

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

       [OperationContract]
        claimantResponse SaveClaimant(claimant claimant);

        [OperationContract]
         claimantResponse RenewExpiry(claimantMin claimantMin);

        [OperationContract]
         claimantResponse getAccessCode(claimantMin claimantMin);
    }
```

**ServiceImplementation:**

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
    {


        public claimantResponse SaveClaimant(claimant claimant)
        {
            return new claimantBLL().SaveClaimant(claimant);
        }


        public claimantResponse RenewExpiry(claimantMin claimantMin)
        {
            return new claimantBLL().RenewExpiry(claimantMin);
        }

        public claimantResponse getAccessCode(claimantMin claimantMin)
        {
            return new claimantBLL().getAccessCode(claimantMin);
        }


    }
```

**Data:**

```
[DataMember]
public class claimantResponse 
    {
       private List<string> _ErrorMessage = new List<string>();

       [DataMember]
       public List<string> ErrorMessage
        {
            get { return _ErrorMessage; }
            set { _ErrorMessage = value; }
        }

       private List<int> _ErrorCode = new List<int>();

       [DataMember]
       public List<int> ErrorCode
       {
           get { return _ErrorCode; }
           set { _ErrorCode = value; }
       }

       [DataMember]
        public String FormStatus { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
        public DateTime ExaminationDate { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
        public String AccessCode { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
        public String Status { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string temp2 { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: running service]

It shows two strange methods getdata and getdataobject instead of my own methods.. :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how are your classes `claimant` and `claimantMin` defined? Also should claimantResponse` be decorated with `DataContractAttribute` and not `DataMemberAttribute`

Comment: Hi Jehof, i have defined these both custom types in a seperate project and then i am referencing them in my service project, should i remove datamember tag from all attributes?

Comment: no only from the class definition. i´m not sure if it is only a typo in your question.

Comment: let me explain, if i create seperate services for each function it works perfect, but not comibining then, so this is the issue and i am unable to detect that.

Comment: Does claimantMin decorated with [DataContract]? and [DataMember] for members? and [DataMember] for class claimantResponse should be  [DataContract]

Comment: What does your service config file look like in the services section or how are you specifying which contract interface to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution to this problem and posting here so might help any body else with same scenario:

1) Removing [DataMember] attribute from the class and properties.
2) creating a new WCF simple service and putting same code worked.

i did remove datamember attribute from the old service but it was not working, so i assume my service was got corrupted because it was not showing any new method that a new service did :(

3) web.cofig would remain same from the time you you created sample of wcf and no change is required in this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have posted will not compile. Due to the data member attribute on the class.

If you then press "run anyway" (cannot remember the exact text, but something close to that). Then it will run the last version of the code that compiled. The method names that you are seeing could have been in the original template  that you used to create the service.

Comment: Replace the [DataMember] attribute on the class with [DataContract]

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by simply restarting Visual Studio 2012 :-)

My version of the problem was that renaming methods and removing the OperationContract attribute off an interface did not make a change to the methods I saw when I ran WCF test client. I even commented out a method and Visual Studio ran the debugger for that method! I restarted Visual Studio and it was back to normal.

Comment: this resolved my issue. I added a method in interface. however it's not picking up the method , however i can see the wsdl. I was working in flash bulider, and the error i am getting is "Unable to find method name" something like that.

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same issue and could not see any new method that added regardless of Datacontract

first thing you need to have to expose your methods will be Data Annotation (attribute)  OperationContract above your method inside the interface like the example below:


    `[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService 
    { 
        [OperationContract]
        Student_Identification GetStudentIdentification(int StudentId);
    }`

This was my first problem but I still couldn't see it, so I decide to update my service reference in the app where its being referenced

[image]

When I clicked Update Service Reference, an error message displayed saying it was unable to connect to server. In my case, the service was pointing to a different server. But I needed to point to my local computer, so I clicked Configure Service Reference

[image]

An there was my problem, the client address was set to a different url and not my local dev machine. I tried adding a host entry in my host file with the existing url the service was using and that still didn't fix my issue. So I went ahead and opened IIS since I have this project setup locally. selected my site, right clicked and selected Edit Bindings...

[image]

Click add and add the url address in the service and dont forgot to add it to you host file just in case. commonly located here -> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
[image]

go back to the app thats referencing the service, right click service reference and select update service reference. This worked for me hopefully this helps someone on their journey.